# Norm of integral operator in $L^1(0,2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

How exactly do I show that an integral operator is bounded. For example, consider the following operator

$$ T: L^1(0,2) \to L^1(0,2)\\ (Tf)(x):=\int_0^x tf(t) dt$$

My first approach
\begin{align}
||(Tf)(x)||_1 &= \int_0^2 |Tf| dx \\
&= \int_0^2 \left| \int_0^x tf(t) dt\right|dx \\
&\leq \int_0^2  \int_0^x |tf(t)| dtdx \\
&\leq \int_0^2 \left(\int_0^x |f(t)|dt\right)\left(\int_0^x |t| dt\right) dx
\end{align}

where for $x=2$, we have $||(Tf)(x)||_1\leq 4||f||_1$.

does this seem correct ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definition of $Tf$ has $tf(x) dt$, and in the proof, you have $tf(t)dt$. Which is correct?

Comment: @5xum The correct one is $tf(t)dt$. Thanks.

Comment: Your first inequality is correct. Then, try estimating $|t| \le x$ -- or indeed $|t| \le 2$.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem correct (and by correct I mean "true and proven to be true") to me, here is where I am doubtful:

- How do you know that $$\int_0^x |tf(t)|dt\leq \int_0^x|f(t)|dt\int_0^x|t|dt?$$
  Can you justify this inequality?
- Assuming that the inequality is correct, How do you get from the last inequality to $||(Tf)(x)||_1\leq 4||f||_1$? What do you mean by "where $x=2$"? The expression you have on the right is *NOT* a function of $x$, because $x$ is the variable you integrate by, so you cannot just say $x=2$!